# How to colorize objects in pino

Tags: javascript, logging, terminal, pino

When i print a object in pino the object has no color highlights.

```js
logger.info({a:"a"})
```

Comment: I don't know pino at all, but from its [website](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-install-setup-and-use-pino-to-log-node-js-applications/#prettifying-json-logs-in-development), I conclude that it is a logger which produces JSON output, and therefore there is no relationship to "coloring", except that we can think of JSON syntax highlighting. Perhaps you could describe exactly what you want  to get here.